# Why the value is not changing what mistake I'm doing here?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here the value in input section is not changing it is static I do not know what mistake I'm doing here..

Here is the code with state and return code..

And in Output section it showing patient id and procedure and it is static i can't change it idk what happend.

```
 const [patient_info, setPatient_info] = useState({
    patientid: "",
    procedure: "",
  });
 const handlePatient = (e) => {
    
    const { name, value} = e.target;
    if (value) {
      if (name === "patientid")
        setPatient_info({ ...patient_info, [name]: value });
      else if (name === "procedure")
        setPatient_info({ ...patient_info, [name]: value });
    }
    else setPatient_info({...patient_info, [name]:""});
    console.log(patient_info.patientid);
  };
    <Typography
                color="#05445E"
                fontFamily="'Jost', sans-serif"
                fontSize={15}
              >
                Patient ID :{" "}
                <Input
                  disableUnderline="true"
                  value={"Patient ID"}
                  name="patientid"
                  fullWidth
                  className={classes.input_2}
                  onChange={handlePatient}
                />
              </Typography>
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0v70.png)

I tried various way but it didn't work. What I want is whenever I enter the data the in input section it should show in console log simultaneously. If anyone can help I will be grateful thank you

Comment: You’re logging patient info before the state is set **and** setting state is an asynchronous operation. And, oddly, setting the “[name]” state to an empty strings right after setting it to ”value”, which is non-sensical.

Comment: I have changed it now. And now it is giving in log when i enter second letter for example if i type a then i type b it will show a first then when i type 3rd letter it will show b

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have `value={"Patient ID"}`. Replace by `value={patient_info.patientid}` and it should work

Comment: Brother can you explain me please what is the difference between the two?

Comment: What you did is just pass a string as a value that never updates so it will be the same everytime. The second, you bind your state to the value of the input so everytime you type something it will update your store and show it in the input

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand how react hooks work. Also, I suggest you refer to [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://airbnb.io/javascript/react/) for practising your JavaScript skills.

```
// which is a hardcoded value, it always is "Patient ID"
value={"Patient ID"}
```

```
// var means that the dynamic variable
value={var}
```

and now you wanted to get the value from the state

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Demo = () => {
    const [patient_info, setPatient_info] = useState({
        patientid: "",
        procedure: "",
    });
    const handlePatient = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        if (value && (name === "patientid" || name === "procedure")) {
            setPatient_info({ ...patient_info, [name]: value });
        } else {
            setPatient_info({ ...patient_info, [name]: "" });
        }
    };

    return <>
        <div
            color="#05445E"
            fontFamily="'Jost', sans-serif"
            fontSize={15}
        >
            Patient ID :{" "}
            <input
                value={patient_info.patientid}
                name="patientid"
                fullWidth
                onChange={handlePatient}
            />
        </div>
    </>
}

export default Demo;
```